# Is there a command-line method to replace a layer in a PSD and save to a JPG? (the goal is to automate compositing)

Tags: command-line, adobe-photoshop, automation, gimp

I have a lot of PSD files that have a Replace Me layer. It'd be nice if I could figure out how to replace that layer and render it to a JPG automatically.

The solution doesn't have to use Photoshop... Maybe its possible with GIMP or some other tool(s)?

Comment: What OS are you doing this in?

Comment: Doesn't matter, I'd prefer linux then windows then macos..

Comment: How can this layer be identified? And can you provide a minimal sample PSD file?

Comment: this can be done, but please provide more information. do all the files have the same dimensions, what kind is the layer (smart obj, shape, text or raster) and is the layer on top of everything else? providing a sample file would be great.